# Python windows script subprocess continues to output after script ends

Tags: python, windows, subprocess

Hi I am writing a python script in windows and using subprocess

I have a line like

> results=subprocess.Popen(['xyz.exe'],stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

After the script ends, and I get back to the promp carrot in cmd, I see more output from the script being printed out. 
I'm seeing stuff like

> Could Not Find xxx_echo.txt

Being printed out repeatedly.

How do I properly close the subprocess in windows?

Comment: How are you closing the subprocess?

Comment: @cwallenpoole lol. I wasn't...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Could Not Find xxx_echo.txt` looks like an error message, which would likely be printed on stderr. Your call to `Popen()` does not collect the child's stderr output, so it will be printed in your terminal.

If your script does not wait for the child to complete, the child may still be executing after your script has exited. You should call `wait()` to wait for the child to complete execution. If you don't want to wait, call `terminate()` to terminate the child process.

You should also collect the stderr if you don't want it dumped to the terminal.

```
child = subprocess.Popen(['xyz.exe'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
child.wait()
print child.returncode
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to call results.kill() or results.terminate() (they are aliases on Windows) to end your subprocesses before exiting your main script.

Answer (score 0):

You have to call the `terminate()` method:

```
results.terminate()
```

There is also `kill()` for stuck sub-processes.